# Gunicorn queue wait time

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

My setup is nginx => gunicorn => django. I am using gunicorn with sync workers. Can I find out how long requests take till they find an available gunicorn worker?

I will use this measure to find out if I have too little workers and thus increase the count, does that make sense? I have the RAM available, as currently I am only using 50% of it, but if they aren't queued up I will use the RAM for something else.

Can I somehow tell nginx or gunicorn master to annotate the wait time in queue?

Comment: Depending on what you're working on, a hacky way to figure this out is doing a load test with something like: https://locust.io/ You can try adjusting the number of gunicorn workers, their type, # of threads, etc and see if the response times go up or down based on the number of requests per second in locust. This only works if you're testing an app that go down or become unresponsive without being a big deal...